# Como saber se um número decimal é par ou ímpar?

Tags: php

Tem várias perguntas relacionados com essa pergunta, mas sempre se tratando de números inteiros.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php

function evenOdd($number){
    $conta = $number / 2;
    $resto = $number % 2;

    if($resto == 0.0)
        echo $conta.' - Par';
    else
        echo $conta.' - Ímpar';
}

evenOdd(11.8); 
echo ' | ';
evenOdd(10.8);
echo ' | ';
evenOdd(5.075);
echo ' | ';
evenOdd(4.39);
```

Qual é a essência para saber se é par ou ímpar ?

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem sua duvida, mas pra identificar se é par ou impar sempre dividimos o valor por dois e verificamos o resto dessa divisão. Exemplo:

5/2 = 2 e resta 1, então é considerado impar.
8/2 = 4 e resta 0 então é par

Comment: @WagnerSoares acho que você não entendeu mesmo. Ele quis dizer para números decimais (fracionados). Pelo o que eu estou lendo no Wikipédia o conceito de "par" ou "impar" só se aplica a numerais inteiros. Agora não sei se é verídico, não frago tanto assim de matemática.

Comment: Verdade, decimais não são classificados como par ou impar.

Um número par é um inteiro na forma n = 2 k, onde k é um inteiro. Os números pares são portanto ..., -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ... 

Um número ímpar é um inteiro na forma n = 2 k + 1, onde k é um inteiro. Os números pares são portanto ..., -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, ... 

0,5 não é inteiro. Logo, não é par nem ímpar.

Comment: Fechei pq no fim pra verificar dá na mesma do que já foi respondido. Indiquei uma que não fala nada de inteiros, então qualquer resposta e consideração sobre inteiros, decimais, float caberia lá.

Comment: Por que essa pergunta foi negativada ? Está até fechada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já explicados pelo @jbueno, só inteiros podem ser classificados como par ou ímpar.

Para um número ser Par, é necessário:

- Ser um número inteiro múltiplo de dois, isto é, ele pode ser escrito na forma 2x;
- Ser divisível por 2;
- Ser cercado por número ímpares;
- Poderem ser divididos em dois grupos com um número inteiro igual de elementos;
- Ser compatível com todas as regras das somas/subtrações e produtos de números pares e ímpares.

Se não for não atender as regras acima, logo ele é Ímpar.

Na prática, para saber se um número é PAR, basta checar se o resto da divisão por 2 é igual a 0 (zero)

```
function ePar($numero){
    if($numero % 2 == 0){ // se o resto da divisão do número por 2 = 0
       return true; // é par
    }else{
       return false; // não é par
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var_dump(ePar(43));
var_dump(ePar(44));
var_dump(ePar(46.7));
```

Saída:

> bool(false)
>
> bool(true)
>
> número informado não é inteiro

Answer (score 3):

Esta é mais uma dúvida de matemática do que de PHP em si. Somente números **inteiros** podem ser classificados em par ou ímpar.

Respondendo a sua pergunta.

> Qual é a essência para saber se é par ou ímpar?

É só conferir o módulo (resto) da divisão por 2, se o resto for 0 o numero é par, se for 1 o número é ímpar. Portanto, todos os números terminados em 1, 3, 5, 7 e 9 são ímpares, os terminados em 0, 2, 4, 6 e 8 são pares.